# no sound on playing videos using vlc beta on nexus 4

Tags: vlc

I have nexus4 . i installed vlc beta from this link as default player couldn't play all formats.while playing videos on phone, it showed only video , no audio. 
video is alright.

Comment: What is 'this link'?

Comment: Plus: Did you check the videos with another player? Maybe they do not have any audio track.

Comment: after upgrade it worked all fine. thank for voting negative :(

Answer (score 0):

Try another player for the device
of try the same video file in a different format if possible.

This will determin if the the video or not.

It's most likely that the vlc player doesn't support that file format as well.

Your best chance is to t another player like MX Player or BSPlayer (googled that).

Video players for mobiles are more limited on what formats they can play.

Reference/guide for you: http://www.real.com/resources/mobile-video-player